# How does the UK electronics travel ban affect my travel without check-in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, uk, airport-security, hand-luggage, electronic-items

Tomorrow I'm flying with Pegasus Airlines from Iran to London with a short layover in Turkey. I just noticed that electronics like e-readers are not allowed in carry-on. However I travel without check-in luggage to save money.

[According to](https://www.gov.uk/hand-luggage-restrictions/electronic-devices-and-electrical-items) the UK government website:

> Flights to the UK from Turkey, Lebanon, Jordan, Egypt, Tunisia, and
> Saudi Arabia.
>
> You must put all phones, laptops, tablets and ereaders -
> and some accessories that can be used with them - in your hold luggage
> if they’re larger than any of these measurements:
>
> - 16cm in length
> - 9.3cm in width
> - 1.5cm in depth (thickness)

My Kobo H2O ereader has the following specs:

- Width 12,9 cm
- Depth 0,97 cm
- Height 17,9 cm

Will I be able to take my reader in carry-on? Or do I have to pay for check in? Or is it possible to leave it with the crew inside the plane?

Comment: [The Pegasus website](https://www.flypgs.com/en/press-room/announcement/new-hand-baggage-security-requirements-on-flights-to-united-kingdom) says "Transit guests must hand over the electronic devices which are not permitted to be carried on board at the boarding gate of their flights to the UK." That implies they have some way of collecting your devices and putting them aside for you if you're taking a connecting flight, but I have no information as to how this process works exactly, so this isn't an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every airline has a slightly different procedure for handling the UK Electronics Ban.

Pegasus has a [statement on their website](https://www.flypgs.com/en/press-room/announcement/new-hand-baggage-security-requirements-on-flights-to-united-kingdom) which includes :

> 4. Transit guests must hand over the electronic devices which are not permitted to be carried on board at the boarding gate of their flights
>      to the UK.

I am not familiar with exactly what Pegasus is doing, but most airlines will accept the electronics at the boarding gate, put them into some form of secure/protective packaging, and then carry them in the aircraft hold.  On arrival int he UK, the electronics will be made available either at the gate when dis-boarding, or at baggage claim.

The Pegasus staff at either Iran or Istanbul will be able to tell you the exact procedure.

Comment: I've read this,Is this for transfers to the UK, or transfere in the UK though?

Comment: Transferring to flights headed to the UK.  The ban only effects flights INTO the UK, not those departing the UK, so once you're there it's irrelevant.

Comment: The US has now removed the electronics restrictions for flights from Turkey.  The UK ban is still in effect, but I would not be surprised to see it removed in the near future, so keep an eye on the news before you travel to see the latest.